# When to mmap() or read() a file, is there a rule of thumb?

Tags: file, compression, osx-mavericks, mmap

I'm tinkering with a Mac utility that does HFS compression. Originally it'd read the entire file into memory using `read(2)`, then create a compressed representation which would then be saved to the file's extended attributes or resource fork. The utility can handle multiple files in parallel.
It can be quite memory hungry so I started my tinkering to mmap the target file instead, using `MAP_PRIVATE` (my hope was also that the mmap might fail if the file was already in use by another process, at least sometimes). So I have

```
inBuf = mmap(NULL, filesize, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_NOCACHE, 0);
```

instead of

```
inBuf = malloc(filesize);
```

Memory use is indeed lower, but somewhat to my surprise I find a decrease in performance: noticeably longer processing times, a lower CPU load and a considerably higher number of major faults (according to tcsh's `time` utility). That impact appears to be more important when the files are smaller, so I have set an arbitrary limit (64Mb) under which the original malloc+read path is used.

Is there a rule of thumb for this sort of trade-off?
I'd run this through perf on Linux, but the comparable utilities I know of on Mac are all geared towards GUI apps (while mine is a shell app, of course).

EDIT: Come to think of it, using mmap() will probably not really decrease memory requirements, will it? I'm guessing data is still going to be copied into "fast RAM" as opposed to accessed directly on disk - and the fact that you can apparently have multiple independent mmaps of the same file seems to support that hypothesis:
- I get a file's content by mmapping it into memory (inBuf above)
- I "hfs-compress" that buffer, and rewrite the file with the compressed content
- `inBuf` doesn't appear to change because of the rewrite, but then HFS compressed files are uncompressed transparently when read
- I get a new mmap of the now compressed file, and as a verification I compare that with `inBuf`: the contents are identical. But you'd also expect that if those mmaps always reflect the content of the file so I'm not certain if my verification makes any sense.

Comment: It could be different on Linux and on MacOSX. I guess that `MAP_NOCACHE` should not be used, if performance matters. You could want to use [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) and/or [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html). At last, benchmarks could be file system specific

Comment: Why do you think that about MAP_NOCACHE? As far as I can tell it does not make a performance difference (when running "alone"), it should make it easier for the system to reclaim unused memory quicker.

Comment: Because in practice the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) is generally improving performance a lot. You'll better trust your kernel, it is generally very well tuned (of course there are exceptions)

Comment: I think the reason why I don't see a consistent performance benefit from caching (in the testing I've been doing) is that I'm working with considerable memory pressure. To paraphrase that WP article: page caching is a good idea if you have "otherwise unused RAM" but if you have very little of that it's probably better to use whatever free RAM you have for whatever it is you're trying to get done. I did try using `madvise()`; interestingly it did NOT help to hint at sequential use of the input buffer so the jury is still out on that.

Comment: Then, have you used `posix_fadvise` ? Otherwise, for large files, use `read` with a buffer of at least a megabyte (and probably 8 or 16 or 32 megabytes)

Comment: I get the impression that madvise and posix_fadvise do exactly the same thing but I could try. As to `read`: I already read the entire file into in a single go.

Comment: I am not sure that a *huge* single POSIX `read` (of e.g. a gigabyte at once) is optimal. You need to benchmark. The rumor is that usually it is better to read a few megabytes at once. Of course, you should benchmark, it is very computer specific (and might not matter that much)